# Saving UIImage in custom pixel dimension

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the below implementation to save a `UIView` as an image to the device's photo album. It works correctly, however the saved image adapts to the device's screen resolution. As an instance if I run it on a iPhone 5, the saved image will be `640 x 640 px`. My goal is to save custom sized images like `1800 x 1800 px` or something like that on every device. So I would really appreciate if somebody could give me an example or any guidance, that helps me to find the right solution. Any other tips welcomed, my goal is to make custom pixel sized images, it doesn't matter if I have to use a different implementation.

```
- (IBAction)saveImg:(id)sender {

    UIImage *imageToSave = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    // self.fullVw holds the image, that I want to save
    imageToSave = [self.fullVw pb_takeSnapshot];

    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToSave);

    UIImage *imageToSave2 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    imageToSave2 = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave2,nil, nil, nil);
}

// This method is in a UIView category
- (UIImage *)pb_takeSnapshot {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.opaque, 0.0);
    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Add the implementation of `pb_takeSnapshot`

Comment: @dan I've added it. It's in a `UIView` category.

Comment: @cimp23 it is not possible without stretching image because when you do screenshot you deal with device screen resolution and you can't have 1800x1800 on iPhone device with screen 640x480.

Comment: @JohnTracid is there any alternative way to do it? A lot of apps doing that, do you have any idea how they accomplish it?